# Youtube embed start time convert to time in seconds directly in array from regex group

Tags: php, youtube

I want to extend one php package which returns embed code from YouTube. I want to extend it and make embed code  with start time querystring.

Piece of Code:

```
        'website' => 'http://youtube.com',
        'ssl'     => true,
        'url'     => [
            '^(https?://)?(?:www\.)?youtu\.be/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]{11})',
       '^(https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com/(?:embed/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:.+&t=)(\S+)',


        ],
        'info'    => [
            'id'     => '{1}',
            'url'    => '{protocol}://youtu.be/{1}',
            'dataUrl' => '{protocol}://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{1}?v=2&alt=jsonc',
            'imageRoot'   => '{protocol}://img.youtube.com/vi/{1}/',
        ],
        'render'  => [
            // iframe attributes
            'sizeRatio' => 1.77,
            'iframe' => [
                'src'     => '{protocol}://www.youtube.com/embed/{1}?rel=0&wmode=transparent&start={3}',
                'width'   => 560,
                'height'  => 315,
                'allowfullscreen' => null,
                'frameborder'     => 0,
            ],
```

{3} is a start time from YouTube in format like 1h22m59s or 22m59s or 59s. I am getting {3} from regex from the last group : (?:.+&t=)(\S+)',

Is it possible to run function directly in array value to convert {3} time in seconds? For embed videos I need &start=123 (not ?start=1h22m59s )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by editing package source. It was the best solution.